# Get rid of Crystal Report generated files in temp folder - Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I have pasted below a piece of code where I am displaying a report. I am using Visual Studio 2008 Crystal Report engine. It works all good with the piece of code

**Problem:** Everytime a report is being run it generates a ('.*tmp', '.*rpt') files typically in a temp folder **c:\windows\temp** however we can get rid of the *.tmp files by setting a recycle on the application pool but need a way to get rid of the .rpt files.

**Found solution:** Call **Close()** and **Dispose()** on the report object. The way I am doing is crReportDoc.Close() then crReportDoc.Dispose()

**Actual Problem:** If **Dispose()** is called the report comes up with the following error ***'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'***

I will really appreciate if one of the fellow mates can help me with a solution as I am quite new to programming.

Thanks

```
        Dim crReportDoc = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument           
        crReportDoc = Session("ReportDocument")
        ReportViewer.DisplayToolbar = True
        ReportViewer.EnableDrillDown = True
        ReportViewer.DisplayGroupTree = False
        ReportViewer.Visible = True
        ReportViewer.DisplayToolbar = True
        ReportViewer.ReportSource = crReportDoc
```

Answer (score 2):

Some times even though you call dispose on your `ReportDocument` object followed by `GC.Collect()` still the `.rpt` files in **Temp** folder are not cleaned up. And there is a limit to no. of `.rpt` files in a Temp folder after which CR stops executing further report requests.

Strangely this happens when you declare your ReportDocument object in side a function or event handler.

But if you declare your ReportDocument in a **Page wide global Context** then crystal reports happily cleans of temp .rpt files when you call the Dispose method in the `Page_Unload()` event !!!!

Answer (score 1):

For CRystal Report Versions 13 and above. To clear temporary files. Call the dispose in the CrystalReportViewer's Unload event

protected void crReportViewer_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseReport();
        }

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to clear the temporary files created by Crystal Reports
    /// </summary>
    protected void CloseReport()
    {
        try
        {
            if(cryRpt != null)
            {
                Sections objSections = cryRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections;
                foreach (Section objSection in objSections)
                {
                    ReportObjects objReports = objSection.ReportObjects;
                    foreach(ReportObject rptObj in objReports)
                    {
                        if(rptObj.Kind.Equals(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject))
                        {
                            SubreportObject subreportObject = (SubreportObject)rptObj;
                            ReportDocument subReportDocument = subreportObject.OpenSubreport(subreportObject.SubreportName);
                            subReportDocument.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                cryRpt.Close();
                cryRpt.Dispose();
            }
            if(crReportViewer != null)
            {
                crReportViewer.ReportSource = null;
                crReportViewer.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
```